# Highcharts x-axis cannot be seen when range is huge

Tags: javascript, highcharts

My x-axis has a range of one year with a one hour interval. I am currently using variwide so the each bar's width will be depending on the number of hours. The problem here is that if the range is too huge, the bars cannot be seen. Is it possible to make it so the x-axis can be seen no matter how huge the range is? Thanks in advance.

Below is a picture of the chart with a 24-hour range:

https://jsfiddle.net/adamloh/bo9s8u4q/6/ (mock)
[image: Picture of chart with 24-hour range]

This is the picture of the chart with a 1-year range. I enabled crosshair (circled blue) which can barely been seen:

https://jsfiddle.net/adamloh/5d28uq6f/2/ (mock)
[image]

Below is my highcharts code:

```
Highcharts.chart('rulecontainer', {
    chart: {
        zoomType: 'x'
    },
    tooltip: {
        enabled: false
    },
    title: {
        text: '',
        style: {
            display: 'none'
        }
    },
    xAxis: {
        events: {
            setExtremes: syncExtremes
        },
        type: 'datetime',
        min: data.minDate,
        max: data.maxDate,
        crosshair: true
    },
    yAxis: [{
        min: data.yMin,
        max: 1,
        title: {
            text: 'kw/h'
        }
    }],
    series: [{
        name: data.ruleName,
        type: 'variwide',
        data: [{
            x: data.dateOccured,
            y: data.yValue,
            z: data.duration
        }],
        borderColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.2)',
        color: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.2)',
        pointRange: 0
    }],
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            minPointLength: 10
        },
        area: {
            fillOpacity: 0.1,
            lineWidth: 1,
            states: {
                hover: {
                    lineWidth: 1
                }
            },
            threshold: null
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi @Adam Loh, Could you reproduce that problem with sample data in some online code editor? You can start from: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/

Comment: @ppotaczek appreciate the info. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable `startOnTick` and `endOnTick` options:

```
xAxis: {
    ...,
    startOnTick: true,
    endOnTick: true
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/pq0yLsj2/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.startOnTick

https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.endOnTick

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek. It is still not working. https://jsfiddle.net/adamloh/5d28uq6f/  I can however see the chart when I remove the startontick and endontick.

Comment: Hi @Adam Loh, Sorry for misunderstanding. That is a Highcharts bug reported here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/11510. It is already fixed in the master branch - https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/nzj8ae1k/ - and will be officially included in the next release.

Comment: Your answer partly helped. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You are using datetime type which may cause your problem

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    title: {
        text: 'Highcharts variwide series on a datetime axis'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        min: Date.UTC(2018, 8, 21, 0, 0),
        max: Date.UTC(2018, 8, 22, 0, 0),
        crosshair: true
    },
    yAxis: [{
        type: 'datetime',
        gridLineWidth: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Lap'
        },
        labels: {
            format: '{value:%M:%S}'
        }
    }],
    series: [{
        name: 'Lap',
        type: 'variwide',
        data: [{
            x: Date.UTC(2018, 8, 21, 7, 50),
            y: 3.45 * 60000,
            z: 5 * 60000
        }, {
            x: Date.UTC(2018, 8, 21, 21, 55),
            y: 3.25 * 60000,
            z: 10 * 60000,
            color: 'rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.2)'
        }, {
            x: Date.UTC(2018, 8, 21, 15, 5),
            y: 3.05 * 60000,
            z: 4 * 60000
        }],
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: 'Pace: {point.y:%M:%S} min/km<br>Lap time: {point.z:%M:%S} min'
        },
        borderColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.2)',
        color: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.2)',
        pointRange: 0
    }]
});
```

```css
#container {
 max-width: 800px;
 min-width: 380px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/variwide.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Hi Anik. I still need the x-axis's range to be 1 year.

Comment: Ok let me clear you about something. When you want to use a large range something like one year and your value is between minutes our chart won't be visible due to your range

Comment: Hi Anik. I already edited the values and put it to at least 1 hour value but only values more than 6 can be seen https://jsfiddle.net/adamloh/5d28uq6f/1/ Is a minimum width possible?